# How to add citations in style [xx-yy] in LyX?

Tags: lyx

I'm writing my thesis using LyX editor. I use bibtex biography for citing papers. I use 'unsrt' style. When I cite multiple references on pdf I get them listed like [1,2,3,4,5] etc. not [1-5] like in most papers. How do I get it in latter style?
Thanks.

PS: I'm using 'thesis' template from examples for writing my thesis.

Comment: Try adding `\usepackage{cite}` to Document --> Settings --> LaTeX preamble.

Answer (score 0):

Add `\usepackage{cite}` to Document --> Settings -->LaTeX preamble.

Comment: This is the same as the comment by Torbjorn T.